# Loading multiline columnusing external table in Oracle

Tags: oracle

Loading a flat file using external table.Some of the fields are being missed out due to multiline values in a column
how can we load all the records including multiline columns?

**Data sample**:

```
--first line
56585,0,4032,,1,790035190,,2,2,,1,1,1,06-SEP-07,,,,,0,EUR ,0,06-SEP-07,1,790035190,2,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,2,2,2,,,,,,,,06-SEP-07,,,,,,,,,1,,,,,,,,,,,
--second line
24188,31,4032,This is the Title,1,790035190,,2,2,,1,1,1,06-SEP-07,,,,,0,EUR ,0,06-SEP-07,1,790035190,2,,0,,Value 1
Value 2
Value 3
Value 4,,,,,,,,,,2,2,2,,,,,,,,06-SEP-07,,,,,,,,,1,,,,,,,,,,,1
```

**External table schema**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE OFFERS_EXT
(
  OFFER_ID                      NUMBER(10)      ,
  AMENDMENT_ID                  NUMBER(10)      ,
  CLIENT_ID                     NUMBER(10)      ,
  BUSINESS_UNIT_NAME            VARCHAR2(120 BYTE),
  RED_FLAG_STATUS               NUMBER(10)      ,
  CREATED_BY                    VARCHAR2(30 BYTE) ,
  RED_FLAG_COMMENTS             VARCHAR2(765 BYTE),
  OFFER_CATEGORY_ID             NUMBER(10)      ,
  OFFER_PRIORITY_ID             NUMBER(10)      ,
  OFFER_PRIORITY_COMMENTS       VARCHAR2(765 BYTE),
  OFFER_STATUS_ID               NUMBER(10)      ,
  SOLD_IN                       NUMBER(10),
  END_TYPE_ID                   NUMBER(10)      ,
  OFFER_START_DATE              DATE,
  OFFER_DUE_SUBMITTED_DATE      DATE,
  VALIDITY_DATE                 DATE,
  CONTRACT_SIGNED_DATE          DATE,
  CONTRACT_START_DATE           DATE,
  CONTRACT_DURATION             NUMBER(5),
  TOTAL_OFFER_VALUE             VARCHAR2(57 BYTE),
  NUMBER_OF_OFFER_SITES         NUMBER(10),
  CREATED_TIMESTAMP             DATE            ,
  LANGUAGE_ID                   NUMBER(10)      ,
  LAST_UPDATED_BY               VARCHAR2(30 BYTE) ,
  TIME_RISK_ID                  NUMBER(10)      ,
  RISK_COMMENTS                 VARCHAR2(765 BYTE),
  PROBABILITY_OF_WIN            NUMBER(5),
  PROBABILITY_OF_WIN_DATE       DATE,
  COMMENTS                      VARCHAR2(765 BYTE),
  ADDRESS_ID                    NUMBER(10),
  WIN_LOSS_PRICE                VARCHAR2(3 BYTE),
  WIN_LOSS_DESCRIPTION          VARCHAR2(3 BYTE),
  WIN_LOSS_QUALITY_SERVICE      VARCHAR2(3 BYTE),
  WIN_LOSS_AVAILABILITY         VARCHAR2(3 BYTE),
  WIN_LOSS_INCOMPLETE_PORTFOL   VARCHAR2(3 BYTE),
  WIN_LOSS_REASONS_TEXT         VARCHAR2(765 BYTE),
  WIN_LOSS_COMMENTS             VARCHAR2(765 BYTE),
  WIN_LOSS_CONCLUSIONS          VARCHAR2(765 BYTE),
  SERVICE_RISK_ID               NUMBER(10)      ,
  TECHNICAL_RISK_ID             NUMBER(10)      ,
  FINANCIAL_RISK_ID             NUMBER(10)      ,
  SPECIAL_DISCOUNT              NUMBER(5),
  SPECIAL_DISCOUNT_INSTALLATIO  NUMBER(5),
  DISCOUNT_REASONS              VARCHAR2(765 BYTE),
  DISCOUNT_REPLY                VARCHAR2(765 BYTE),
  WIN_LOSS_DISCOUNT             VARCHAR2(3 BYTE),
  WIN_LOSS_OTHER                VARCHAR2(3 BYTE),
  WIN_LOSS_POLITICAL            VARCHAR2(3 BYTE),
  LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP        DATE            ,
  ORDER_INST_COUNTRY_ID         NUMBER(10),
  FM_ORDER_NR                   VARCHAR2(60 BYTE),
  CONTRACT_END_DATE             DATE,
  BANK_ID                       NUMBER(10),
  BID_TOOL_ID                   NUMBER(10),
  FINANCIAL_RISK_COMMENT        VARCHAR2(765 BYTE),
  SERVICE_RISK_COMMENT          VARCHAR2(765 BYTE),
  TECHNICAL_RISK_COMMENT        VARCHAR2(765 BYTE),
  CONTRACT_CHECK_ID             NUMBER(10),
  CONTRACT_CHECK_DATE           DATE,
  CONTRACT_CHECK_BY             VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
  CONTRACT_CHECK_COMMENTS       VARCHAR2(1536 BYTE),
  CONTRACT_CHECK_REPLY          VARCHAR2(1536 BYTE),
  CONTRACT_PARALLEL_FLAG        NUMBER(1),
  FRC_FLAG                      VARCHAR2(3 BYTE),
  FRC_OFFER_ID                  NUMBER(10),
  FRC_AMENDMENT_ID              NUMBER(10),
  FRC_COPYDATAFLAG              VARCHAR2(3 BYTE),
  CONTRACT_CANCEL_DATE          DATE,
  REFERS_TO_AMENDMENT           NUMBER(10)
)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
  (  TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
     DEFAULT DIRECTORY EXTERNAL_DIR_RE
     ACCESS PARAMETERS 
       ( RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE CHARACTERSET WE8ISO8859P1
         BADFILE REJECT_DIR_RE:'OFFERS_EXT.bad'
         LOGFILE REJECT_DIR_RE:'OFFERS_EXT.log'
         LOAD WHEN (OFFER_ID != 'FILETRAILER')
         FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
         MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
         (
  OFFER_ID                     ,
  AMENDMENT_ID                 ,
  CLIENT_ID                    ,
  BUSINESS_UNIT_NAME           ,
  RED_FLAG_STATUS              ,
  CREATED_BY                   ,
  RED_FLAG_COMMENTS            ,
  OFFER_CATEGORY_ID            ,
  OFFER_PRIORITY_ID            ,
  OFFER_PRIORITY_COMMENTS      ,
  OFFER_STATUS_ID              ,
  SOLD_IN                      ,
  END_TYPE_ID                  ,
  OFFER_START_DATE       date "DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS"       ,
  OFFER_DUE_SUBMITTED_DATE  date "DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS"    ,
  VALIDITY_DATE             date "DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS"    ,
  CONTRACT_SIGNED_DATE      date "DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS"    ,
  CONTRACT_START_DATE       date "DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS"    ,
  CONTRACT_DURATION            ,
  TOTAL_OFFER_VALUE            ,
  NUMBER_OF_OFFER_SITES        ,
  CREATED_TIMESTAMP        date "DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS"    ,
  LANGUAGE_ID                  ,
  LAST_UPDATED_BY              ,
  TIME_RISK_ID                 ,
  RISK_COMMENTS                ,
  PROBABILITY_OF_WIN           ,
  PROBABILITY_OF_WIN_DATE    date "DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS"   ,
  COMMENTS                     ,
  ADDRESS_ID                   ,
  WIN_LOSS_PRICE               ,
  WIN_LOSS_DESCRIPTION         ,
  WIN_LOSS_QUALITY_SERVICE     ,
  WIN_LOSS_AVAILABILITY        ,
  WIN_LOSS_INCOMPLETE_PORTFOL  ,
  WIN_LOSS_REASONS_TEXT        ,
  WIN_LOSS_COMMENTS            ,
  WIN_LOSS_CONCLUSIONS         ,
  SERVICE_RISK_ID              ,
  TECHNICAL_RISK_ID            ,
  FINANCIAL_RISK_ID            ,
  SPECIAL_DISCOUNT             ,
  SPECIAL_DISCOUNT_INSTALLATIO ,
  DISCOUNT_REASONS             ,
  DISCOUNT_REPLY               ,
  WIN_LOSS_DISCOUNT            ,
  WIN_LOSS_OTHER               ,
  WIN_LOSS_POLITICAL           ,
  LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP   date "DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS"    ,
  ORDER_INST_COUNTRY_ID        ,
  FM_ORDER_NR                  ,
  CONTRACT_END_DATE        date "DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS"     ,
  BANK_ID                      ,
  BID_TOOL_ID                  ,
  FINANCIAL_RISK_COMMENT       ,
  SERVICE_RISK_COMMENT         ,
  TECHNICAL_RISK_COMMENT       ,
  CONTRACT_CHECK_ID            ,
  CONTRACT_CHECK_DATE     date "DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS"      ,
  CONTRACT_CHECK_BY            ,
  CONTRACT_CHECK_COMMENTS      ,
  CONTRACT_CHECK_REPLY         ,
  CONTRACT_PARALLEL_FLAG       ,
  FRC_FLAG                     ,
  FRC_OFFER_ID                 ,
  FRC_AMENDMENT_ID             ,
  FRC_COPYDATAFLAG             ,
  CONTRACT_CANCEL_DATE   date "DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS"       ,
  REFERS_TO_AMENDMENT          
         )
       )
     LOCATION (EXTERNAL_DIR_RE:'OFFERS_EXT.dat')
  )
REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED
NOPARALLEL
NOMONITORING;
```

Answer (score 0):

You specified "RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE", i.e. any new line will be treated as new row. If you have multi-line values in your source file you need to use 1) another delimiter for new lines or 2) merge multi-line values into single line before loading using batch script. Is it correct that your multi-line values are not enclosed into double quotes?